# How can we check if a session in MySQL v5.6 is using SSL to connect?

Tags: mysql, session, ssl, tls1.2

Is there a way to query any tables in MySQL v5.6 to understand if the current sessions are using SSL transport or not? Maybe something in the performance_schema tables or anything else?

In MySQL v5.7 and above, there is a way to check this using SHOW SESSION STATUS, and also the x$session table.

I'll not be having server access to check. I can login to the database using client tools and use the admin account to query.